AppleScript always results in the last line being echoed backed in my logs when ran from shell
(Possibly dumb) AppleScript question: I have a simple OSAScript (ran from a bash script function via a Jamf policy) that sets a few Finder Sidebar options for console user. It runs fine, but I noticed that the last line always gets echoed back in my Jamf logs - but does not get echoed back when ran locally in Terminal).
Is this a Jamf thing, a shell thing, or a AppleScript thing?
Example code (truncated for simplicity):
function configure_sidebar() {

    echo "Configuring Finder Sidebar settings for console user..."
    sudo -u "$CONSOLE_USER_NAME" osascript -e '
    activate application "Finder"
    tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Finder"
  
    delay 1.0
    select menu bar 1
    click menu bar item "Finder" of menu bar 1
    delay 0.5
    click menu 1 of menu bar item "Finder" of menu bar 1
    click menu item "Settings…" of menu 1 of menu bar item "Finder" of menu bar 1
  
    repeat until exists window "Finder Settings"
    end repeat
  
    click button "Sidebar" of toolbar 1 of window "Finder Settings"
    
    if (value of checkbox 1 of scroll area 1 of window "Finder Settings" as boolean) then
    click checkbox 1 of scroll area 1 of window "Finder Settings"
    end if
    
    if (value of checkbox 2 of scroll area 1 of window "Finder Settings" as boolean) then
    click checkbox 2 of scroll area 1 of window "Finder Settings"
    end if
    
    if not (value of checkbox 3 of scroll area 1 of window "Finder Settings" as boolean) then
    click checkbox 3 of scroll area 1 of window "Finder Settings"
    end if
   
    end tell
    end tell
    '
}

The script runs fine, but my Jamf logs echo back the following in the last line:
"checkbox 3 of scroll area 1 of window Finder Settings of application process Finder"
(doesn't matter what the last command is, it always gets echoed back regardless, as if Im not closing the OSAScript properly, or it doesn't like being nested in a function).

One observation after additional QA testing: The last command is only echoed to logs if the Finder setting in question has NOT been set by the script yet.
Example: I want to disable Finder preference in checkbox 20 but it is DISABLED already, then I will see the output in logs after the script disables checkbox 20. But if the script runs again - or I manually disable box 20 manually (i.e.; checkbox 20 is DISABLED), the logs no longer echo that last command. Something about the state of the checkbox reflects how the Jamf policy script will get logged.

In general, the last command in an applescript is returned as the result. It's likely that checkbox 3 works and is returned as you've described, then passed on up the chain to be logged. Take only the applescript code and run it in Script Editor. The last line is returned as the result, which is a constant that you can use within the script. You can read about it in the language guide.

When the script does not uncheck the box, then there is no result, and hence, no logging to be done. You can also see this outcome if you run the code in script editor (depending upon the state of the checkbox).

Thank you. Since Im not concerned about seeing this (assuming it's not affecting the goal of my script), I'll just make a note that this behavior is expected and the log can be safely disregarded. I just needed a sanity check for my (lack of) AppleScript skills. Thanks Mockman.

Glad to help. If it does begin to get in the way, you could append some kind of command that doesn't generate a result, then your log should get nothing extraneous to relay.

@Mockman, since your solution is correct (and provides some helpful context besides), care to put it as an Answer so it can be accepted?

In general, the output of the last statement in an applescript is returned as the 'result'. It's likely that checkbox 3 works and is returned as you've described, then passed on up the chain to be logged.
This snippet of code should demonstrate how result works. It assumes that the Finder Preferences are open and the Sidebar tab is active.
If the first checkbox is checked, then the script will uncheck the box and generate a result. If unchecked, then it will do nothing and therefore will not generate a result.
activate application "Finder"
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Finder"
        set wfp to window "Finder Preferences"
        
        if (value of checkbox 1 of wfp as boolean) then -- if checked…
            perform action "AXPress" of checkbox "All My Files" of wfp
        end if
        --> action "AXPress" of checkbox "All My Files" of window "Finder Preferences" of application process "Finder" of application "System Events"
    end tell
end tell

You can read about global constants in the Applescript Language Guide but this is the relevant part:

When a statement is executed, AppleScript stores the resulting value, if any, in the predefined property result. The value remains there until another statement is executed that generates a value. Until a statement that yields a result is executed, the value of result is undefined. You can examine the result in Script Editor by looking in the Result pane of the script window.

So in this case, the initial state of the checkbox determines whether there is a result to be logged. I should add that the result will also appear in Script Editor's log window.
